# How to launch node-gyp from command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, node-gyp

Previously it worked, but in new versions I can't invoke it to rebuild failing dependency:

```
C:\tmp\ofe\node_modules\ofe>node-gyp configure
'node-gyp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `npm install -g node-gyp` and followed the other install requirements from the [docs](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)?

If that's not it, do any of your other globally installed node modules work? If not, perhaps your path is missing the npm global modules directory.